# jQuery: value.attr is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this snipped in my page:

```
$('#category_sorting_form_save').click(function(){
    var elements = $("#category_sorting_elements > div");
    $.each(elements, function(key, value) {
        console.info(key," : ",value);
        console.info("cat_id: ",value.attr('cat_id'));
    });
});
```

And when it is executed, I get:

```
0 : <div class="dragable" cat_id="6" value="" style="opacity: 1;">    
value.attr is not a function
    console.info("cat_id: ",value.attr('cat_id'));
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am trying to get the value of the div.cat_id element.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Contents of that jQuery object are plain DOM elements, which doesn't respond to jQuery methods (e.g. `.attr`). You need to wrap the value by `$()` to turn it into a jQuery object to use it.

```
    console.info("cat_id: ", $(value).attr('cat_id'));
```

or just use the DOM method directly

```
    console.info("cat_id: ", value.getAttribute('cat_id'));
```

Answer (score 10):

You are dealing with the raw DOM element .. need to wrap it in a jquery object

```
console.info("cat_id: ",$(value).attr('cat_id'));
```

Answer (score 5):

The second parameter of the callback function passed to [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) will contain the actual DOM element and not a jQuery wrapper object. You can call the [getAttribute()](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/getAttribute) method of the element:

```
$('#category_sorting_form_save').click(function() {
    var elements = $("#category_sorting_elements > div");
    $.each(elements, function(key, value) {
        console.info(key, ": ", value);
        console.info("cat_id: ", value.getAttribute('cat_id'));
    });
});
```

Or wrap the element in a jQuery object yourself:

```
$('#category_sorting_form_save').click(function() {
    var elements = $("#category_sorting_elements > div");
    $.each(elements, function(key, value) {
        console.info(key, ": ", value);
        console.info("cat_id: ", $(value).attr('cat_id'));
    });
});
```

Or simply use `$(this)`:

```
$('#category_sorting_form_save').click(function() {
    var elements = $("#category_sorting_elements > div");
    $.each(elements, function() {
        console.info("cat_id: ", $(this).attr('cat_id'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the simplist one:

```
$("element").getAttribute("<attribute_name>")
```

if you want to set a value to an attribute

```
$("element").setAttribute("<attribute_name>", "<new_value>")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `jQuery('.class-name').attr("href")`, in my case it works better.

Here more information: ["jQuery(...)" instead of "$(...)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884072/jquery-instead-of)