# "jQuery(...)" instead of "$(...)"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it a good practice to write `jQuery("...")` instead of `$("...")`?

I heard that it might be useful for avoiding future conflicts with other libraries if they use the `$` as well, but is that a real-world concern? Let say I really have no idea what other libraries I'm gonna use in the future, so should I avoid writing `$("...")` in my scripts? Is there any other well known libraries relying on `$` as well?

Also I'd love to know if there is any other issues attached to this subject.

Comment: If you're using the `.ready()` function or shortcut version, then you can just do this: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { /* $ is safe */ });` (Or the shortcut version.) `jQuery(function($) { /* $ is safe */ });` This way there's no need for `.noConflict()` or manual IIFE approaches.

Comment: @CrazyTrain thanks for the explanation! will you post it as an answer? :)

Comment: Sure, I could do that. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's perfectly safe to use the $ for jQuery, it's the jQuery idiom, at least on your own pages which you control.

If you do choose to use jQuery in widgets you can structure it in a way that prevents it from conflicts.

In general jQuery binds to both $ and jQuery so using jQuery alone does not guarantee you safey..

If you are concerned with conflict jQuery does expose the $.noConflit();
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Which relinquishes the control of $ and you can store jQuery in a variable of your choice (or use jQuery).

Here are the libraries that use the $ sign based on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) and this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632041/what-javascript-libraries-are-known-to-use-the-global-dollar-sign-window):

> Scanning this page, the only ones that come to mind are:
>
> 1. jQuery - Provides jQuery.noConflict() to release the $
> 2. Prototype
> 3. MooTools

However jQuery is killing it with about 90% market share..

1. http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/08/14/jquery_used_by_half_of_all_websites/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176324/why-does-everyone-like-jquery-more-than-prototype-script-aculo-us-or-mootools-or

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap your code with sell-invoking function and use name you want

```
(function (JQUERY, otherLIB) {
  // ...
}(jQuery, $))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the `.ready()` function (or shortcut version) to wrap your code, then there's already functionality built in to give you safe access to the jQuery library. That is through defining a function parameter in the callback you provide.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    /* in here, $ is safe */ 
}); 

jQuery(function($) { 
    /* in here, $ is safe */ 
});
```

Since jQuery passes itself as the first argument to the callback, you can just give it any name that you want, including `$`. Because it forms a local parameter, it will be unaffected by and will not affect an identical name in the global space.

This way there's no need for `.noConflict()` or manual IIFE approaches. Everything you need is already right there for you.

Answer (score 2):

$ is now used frequently and might be use by other libraries event if you do not use it. You can use [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back
>   to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). Old references of
>   $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores
>   them, Reference.

Answer (score 2):

The `$` is just a shorthand namespace, due to jQuery being very well known many javascript frameworks tend to view `$` as a reserved namespace and shy away from using it. That said it is very easy for anyone to namespace any code to `window.$`.

If you are conscious about what the `$` namespace refers to exactly you can remove jQuerys bindings to that namespace and rebind it yourself outside of the global scope.

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function($) {

    // your code that can use $ as jQuery namespace

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some other libraries use the dollar sign as well. [Mootools for example](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window%3adollar) can use it too. But there is always the possibility to use jQuerys [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode, so you can quite safely use the dollar sign in your code.