# RateIt jquery plugin creating a conflict with the jquery file that i have in my project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have got two jquery files in my project both of them works separately but when i keep them together they doesn't work. Rate it plugin works separately but when i combine with my project it doesn't works so how can we make the both work together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **$.noConflict()** to avoid conflicts between jquery's files :

Follow this link :

```
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `jQuery` instead of `$` . Like if jQuery and the other plugin uses same structure like `$()` then its better to use `jQuery` or `jq` instead of `$`.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").text("jQuery is still working!");
  });
});
```

Can also be written like:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("button").click(function(){
    jQuery("p").text("jQuery is still working!");
  });
});
```

You can check followings links for more info: [**link1**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_noconflict.asp) and [**link2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884072/jquery-instead-of).