# Typescript+JQuery+Bootstrap Uncaught TypeError: $ is undefined

Tags: jquery, typescript

I have what is probably a simple configuration problem but I'm pretty new to typescript so I'm not really sure what I'm doing at the moment.

**Setup:**
I have a typescript project with the following dependencies (as well as others)

"bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
"bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.9.0",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",

**Problem:**
When I go to my index.html file I get the error message in bootstrap-datepicker.js:1630.:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is undefined

I have these imports in my own .ts files that make use of JQuery

> import * as $ from "jquery";

But this error is coming from another library. I can add a script tag into in my index.html file to a reference a jQuery.js and everything works.  Presumably this is not how I should solve it as jquery would be in my bundle.min file and then repeated as a standalone .js file.  I think I should somehow register $ as a global variable that can be used by other libraries?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you install the typescript definitions for jQuery? `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery`

Comment: You can just use jquery instead of $ as well.  It looks like the code, from the limited knowledge I see here, is trying to redefine $. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884072/jquery-instead-of

Comment: @Kokodoko I have this @types/jquery in my devDependencies.

Comment: @Dale - the error is coming from bootstrap-datepicker.js which is another dependency on my project, so I am not able to change that code.

Answer (score 0):

Today I met the same issue and I resolved it.

Before import bootstrap and its plugin libraries, import jQuery and make it global

```
import $ from 'jquery';

global.$ = $;
global.jQuery = $;

import('bootstrap');
```

Please note that, you'd have to `import('bootstrap');` instead of `import 'bootstrap;`, because the former is dynamic import while the latter is not. Dynamic import will run after `global.$` and `global.jQuery` are defined.

I don't have experience with bootstrap-datepicker but I guess you can just copy my example and append `import('bootstrap-datepicker')`; The key is to make sure this thing is imported AFTER `global.$` and `global.jQuery` are defined.