# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, attr

I'm selecting all child divs of area_enInfantry and looping through to adjust the text of certain ones. cardArray is a global const and myId is defined within the parent function.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAttribute')

```js
var field = $("#area_en" + cardArray[myId]['type']).find("div");

field.each(function(a, element) {
  console.log("cC type:" + cardArray[myId]['type'] + "- index:" + a + " title: " + element[a].attr('title'));

  if (element[a].attr("title").indexOf("player") < 0) { // check this card isn't special player card
    doStuff;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="area_enInfantry">
  <div id="info_enInfantryScore" class="info_Score">-1</div>
  <div class="encardContainer" title="barricade">-1</div>
  <div class="encardContainer" title="spy">2</div>
</div>
```

I read [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4114882/989887) that it may be because the contents of field/element may be DOM elements and that I should wrap them in $() so I did exactly that- changing both variables to $(element)[a].attr('title')
but now I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf') instead, seemingly moving the error to the next line.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Problem looks like that the first element in your .each is info_enInfantryScore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here. Firstly the variable `element` contains a Element object, not a jQuery object, so there is no `attr()` method available.

Secondly, once you correct that, `attr('title')` on the first `div` is not set so is `undefined`. Therefore you'll get an error because you're calling `indexOf()` on an empty value. You can use solve this by coalescing the value to an empty string if null.

Also note that I would assume you want to invoke the `doStuff()` function, so need to add the `()` at the end and it's better practice to use `prop()` over `attr()` where possible.

With that said, try this:

```js
// mock data
let myId = 'foo';
let cardArray = { foo: { type: 'Infantry' } }

let doStuff = () => console.log('do stuff...');
var $field = $("#area_en" + cardArray[myId]['type']).find("div");

$field.each(function(i, element) {
  let $el = $(element);
  console.log("cC type:" + cardArray[myId]['type'] + "- index:" + i + " title: " + $el.prop('title'));
  if (($el.prop("title") || '').indexOf("player") < 0) { // check this card isn't special player card
    doStuff();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="area_enInfantry">
  <div id="info_enInfantryScore" class="info_Score">-1</div>
  <div class="encardContainer" title="barricade">-1</div>
  <div class="encardContainer" title="spy">2</div>
</div>
```