# Fable: Calling a native Javascript function that requires JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, f#, fable-f#

I have F# experience, but am new to Fable (and Javascript, npm, webpack, etc.). In my app, I'm trying to call an external Javascript library called [cardsJS](https://github.com/richardschneider/cardsJS) in order to display playing cards. However, this library requires JQuery, so I'm not sure how to call it from Fable/F#.

To be specific, one of the Javascript functions exposed by the library is:

```js
// Gets the ID of the card, e.g. "KS" for the king of spades.
cid: function (card) {
    var s = card.attr('src');
    return s.substring(s.length - 6, s.length - 4);
},
```

In cardsJS, a card is just an HTML `img` element, so I tried to import the `cid` function in my Fable code via:

```ml
type ICardsJS =
    abstract member cid : HTMLImageElement -> string

let iCardsJS : ICardsJS = importDefault "cardsJS/cards.js"
```

However, when I call `iCardsJS.cid(card)` this way, I get a Javascript runtime error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: card.attr is not a function
    at Object.cid (cards.js:30:26)
```

The problem here is that the library apparently [expects a JQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114870/jquery-value-attr-is-not-a-function), rather than the raw DOM element, so it can call the object's `attr` function. So I guess my F# interface should actually look something like this instead:

```ml
type ICardsJS =
    abstract member cid : JQueryThing??? -> string
```

If I was writing in raw Javascript, I could wrap the DOM element as a JQuery object, like this: `$(card)`. How can I accomplish the same thing in Fable? I'm sure I need to import JQuery into my F# code somehow, but I don't know the right incantation. The only lead I've found so far is [this issue](https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/issues/661), which suggests something like:

```ml
let jq : obj = importDefault "jquery"
let jqCard = jq $ card
```

But that doesn't compile in Fable 3:

```
error FSHARP: Value restriction. The value 'jqCard' has been inferred to have generic type
    val jqCard : obj
```

I think the problem there is that `jq` has the wrong type (`obj` instead of some sort of `IJQuery` interface) and the compiler thinks that `$` is from `Fable.Core.JsInterop`:

```ml
  ///<summary>
  /// Destructure and apply a tuple to an arbitrary value.
  /// E.g. `myFn $ (arg1, arg2)` in JS becomes `myFn(arg1, arg2)`
  ///</summary>
  val ($) : callee: obj -> args: obj -> 'a
```

Comment: How doesn't it compile?

Comment: I've updated my question with the compiler output.

Comment: That's just a good old value restriction. You need to give `jqCard` a type annotation.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that this syntax doesn't work at all in this version of Fable, even if I get it to compile. It looks like I instead need to import JQuery into an `IJQuery` interface, which I maybe have to define manually. There are a few breadcrumbs that mention this, but it's not clearly documented anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried giving `jqCard` a type annotation?